# logical negation of a statement: any mammal that has long ears has at least

Tags: logic, puzzle

Write the negation of the following statement: Any mammal that has long ears has at least one of its predators with yellow eyes having all of its cubs that cannot fly.
Write it in the logical mathematical way.

Comment: It just takes unpacking.  Remember to flip the for all and there exists and to negate the inside.  Where are you having trouble?

Comment: My only trouble is just expressing the statement as it is given, because after that i can easily negate it..@RossMillikan

Comment: Are you trying to write it in English, or in some logical language?  If the latter, you need to define what language.

Comment: yes you are right...i need to write it in logical language @RossMillikan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is to define $P$ as "any mammal that has long ears has at least one of its predators with yellow eyes having all of its cubs that cannot fly" and the negation is $\lnot P$.  Presumably you are supposed to define simpler sentences than that, so $M(x)$ is $x$ is a mammal,$ L(x)$ means $x$ has long ears, and your sentence looks like $\forall x (M(x)\wedge L(x))\implies \dots$  Can you finish?

Comment: i don't really know how to use the latex guide of this page for this logic statement...but i am expressing it with words and after that i hope you correct me.. Let there exist one N(x) such that x is a predator and it has P(x) yellow eyes and let Q(x) the cubes that can fly and this be in negation form..?

Comment: You can see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for $\LaTeX$ and right click and Show Math as -> TeX commands to see how I did anything in any post.  That's how I learned.

Comment: Can you please help me clearly express this one?? @RossMillikan

Comment: The next part of the sentence, "has at least one" would translate to "there exists..."  Can you make progress from here?

Comment: yes i have written it with words in the comment above, i am just having problem with the paranthesis..

Comment: I could have defined $ML(x)$ to be $x$ is a mammal with long ears, then it would have been $\forall x ML(x) \implies \dots$  The problem is not specific in how finely you have to chop the sentence.  That was the point of my first sentence: you can just throw a not in front and be done.  I believe you are supposed to break it down to every phrase, which is why I separated mammal and long ears.  Note the sentence says nothing about non-mammals and non-long eared things, so that is why I have the parentheses around $M(x) \wedge L(x)$.  You need both of those for the sentence to say anything.

Comment: I think the first part was fine as you stated in the beginning because for the negation i just need to change the for every...sign - to there exists a ....,so i won't need to change and negate the mammals and ears part...i have doubts for the second part..can you please express it your way?just the statement is enough, not the negation @RossMillikan and thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

What about this (in a bit free literary form): "All yellow eyes predators of some long ears mammals have flying cubs"?

Vladimir Sotirov

Comment: No, that doesn't really work: "of some long-eared mammals" is not well-defined, at least to this native English speaker.

Comment: Thank you, Tony, that is what I wanted to say in bad English. I think we are wright to say in our case "All A of some B are..." instead of "There are such B that for all A..."?

Comment: No, I disagree. The English language simply doesn't assign a precise meaning to "all A of some B".

Comment: Sure! Of course, we have in mind one and the same predicate formula, but I am trying to translate it in an everyday language more appropriate for a puzzle (passing from Bulgarian to English :)) If we are asked the question "Are there any animals all of whose enemies are flying?" the logically exact answer will be "Yes, there are such animals all of whose enemies..." But I suppose that something like "Oh, yes, all enemies of some reptiles, for instance, are flying" with the natural emphasizing would be relevant, too. I'm sorry, this is rather linguistic matter indeed.

Answer (score 0):

"There is a long-eared mammal, all of whose yellow-eyed predators have flying cubs."

(By the way, cubs never fly. Better is "flying young".)